# Finding the List of words in List of Sentences and return the matching sentences

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension, trigram

From the List of Sentences and List of words, how to return the list of Sentences, only if all three words are matching from words Lists (Trigrams).

Please suggest. Below are example lists.

```
listwords = [['people','suffering','acute'], ['Covid-19','Corona','like'], ['people','must','collectively']]

listsent = ['The number of people suffering acute hunger could almost double.',
            'Lockdowns and global economic recession have',
            'one more shock – like Covid-19 – to push them over the edge',
            'people must collectively act now to mitigate the impact']
```

Output list should be first & last sentences, as they have three matching words in listwords.

Expected output is:

```
['The number of people suffering acute hunger could almost double.',
 'people must collectively act now to mitigate the impact']
```

Comment: add expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Try this solution out:

```
listwords = [['people','suffering','acute'], ['Covid-19','Corona','like'], ['people','must','collectively']]

listsent = ['The number of people suffering acute hunger could almost double.',
            'Lockdowns and global economic recession have',
            'one more shock – like Covid-19 – to push them over the edge',
            'people must collectively act now to mitigate the impact']

# interate through each sentence
for sentence in listsent:
    # iterate through each group of words
    for words in listwords:
        # check to see if each word group is in the current sentence
        if all(word in sentence for word in words):
            print(sentence)
```

I commented the lines to give you an idea of whats going on

The first part of the code iterates through each sentence in your list

```
for sentence in listsent:
```

Then we need to iterate over the groups of words you have in your words list

```
for words in listwords
```

This is where things get fun. Since you have nested lists we need to check to make sure all three words are found in the sentence

```
if all(word in sentence for word in words):
```

Finally you can print out each sentence that contains all the words

```
print(sentence)
```

you could also put this in a function and return found sentences as a new list

```
listwords = [['people','suffering','acute'], ['Covid-19','Corona','like'], ['people','must','collectively']]

listsent = ['The number of people suffering acute hunger could almost double.',
            'Lockdowns and global economic recession have',
            'one more shock – like Covid-19 – to push them over the edge',
            'people must collectively act now to mitigate the impact']


def check_words(listwords, listsent):
    listsent_new = []
    # interate through each sentence
    for sentence in listsent:
        # iterate through each group of words
        for words in listwords:
            # check to see if each word group is in the current sentence
            if all(word in sentence for word in words):
                listsent_new.append(sentence)
    return listsent_new


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check_words(listwords, listsent))
```