# Given a long list of words and list sentences, what is the most optimized way of finding the sentences which contain at least one of the words

Tags: python, lookup-tables

I am here with a very straightforward matching problem.

I have a really large list of words (~100k words) and an even larger list of sentences(~200M), each having an average of 5-7 words. I want to find the sentences which contain at least one of these words.
(I looked at the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61684446/1930402))

Here are some examples:

> **Words:**
>
> name
>
> city
>
> ocean
>
> shop
>
> pizza
>
> man
>
> **Sentences**
>
> There lived a man
>
> Somebody purchased a book
>
> God bless the world
>
> Love you my child
>
> Ocean is polluted
>
> **Matches:**
>
> There lived a man
>
> Ocean is polluted.

The below code is an O(N2) solution.

```
 required_subset=[]
  for word in words:
       for sentence in sentences:
               if word in sentence:
                  required_subset.append(sentence)
```

However, this is just terrible. So, I followed the below approach.

1. Create an inverted index from all words of sentences.
2. Find a match between the words in inv. index and the list of words.
3. Collate all the sentences which are there in the indices.

This is also not very fast.

All I can think of to make it faster is to do multiprocessing, running it on larger computer!

I am reading about `lru_cache`, however, cannot connect this problem with the application.

Comment: Are the sentences plain strings or lists of tokens? Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: The inverted index has to be a big time win, although it will use a lot more memory.  It takes advantage of Python's dictionary hashing to do the searches.